# Is it possible to select only non edge vertices with Python in the BGE?

Tags: python, game-engine

I have a subdivided plane that I'm using with a randomize vertices on the z-axis script, but I want the edges to remain where they are so another plane can fit seamlessly next to it. Is this possible with python and mathutils?

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about Blender or about the BGE (it is possible in both, but I need to know which one you are looking for).

Comment: Oh, hey Monster :) The BGE. I also just made a post on BA about wanting to learn python for procedural map making. I'm having a tough time grasping some of the code needed, so I might not completely even understand the answer to my question...